# JQuery Animate .offset() .position() returns NULL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a JQuery plug in to slide some images from right to left.

I tried to search for a plug in but i thought i'd create it myself.
**What I have:**
- several DIV elements like this:

```
<div class="footer_image_div project">
</div>
```

- i thought if i retrieve all the positions of the projects and animate them to 260 to the left it'd worked

I tried

```
$(function(){
         $('.project').each(function() {
             alert('a');
             var elm = $(this);
             elm.find(".project").animate({}, 500, function(){
                var pos = elm.find(".project").position();
                alert(pos.top);
             });

         });
      });
```

I did try offset aswell both do return NULL.

What should i do?
Where should i look? I am confused

Comment: Why the `elm.find('.project')`? Are they nested? Why not simply `elm`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){
     $('.project').each(function() {
         alert('a');
         var elm = $(this);
         elm.animate({}, 500, function(){
            var pos = elm.position();
            alert(pos.top);
         });

     });
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :D
It does return the position but now i've found out that that isn't really needed.
So i combined both of the answers to this
`code` $("#btn_test").click(function(){
        $('.project').each(function() {
            var elm = $(this);
            elm.animate(
                {
                    left: '+=260px'
                }, 500, function(){         
            });

        });
  });`code` But if i press test it doesn't do anything nor are there errors

Answer (score 0):

```
// This code will work right if `.project` is not nested.

.project {
    position: absolute;
}

$('.project').each(function() {
      var elm = $(this);
      elm.animate({
         left: '+=260px'
      }, 500, function(){
         var pos = elm.position();
      });
 });
```